# Extract last string of a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL like this:

> `http://www.url/name/something/#/venue`

I need to grab the 'venue' from each URL. I have:

```
var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');
var urlParts = currentUrl.split( "/" );
```

The split breaks up the URL.

I'm not sure how to grab the last part of `urlParts`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That would not grab the last occurance as split will return multiple strings for each `/` in the url, edit: you edited your comment which still doesnt work(as it wont necessarily always be a hardcoded length: instead use `urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]` as shown below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the last element of the `urlParts` array:

```
var lastPart = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(location)` why not just use `location` object and `location.hash`? Like this:

```
location.hash.replace('#/', '')
```

For url like `http://www.url/name/something/#/venue` it will give you `venue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this:

```
var url = document.URL.split('#/')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');
var urlParts = currentUrl.split( "/" );
alert(urlParts[urlParts.length-1]);
```

The fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/59mHP/).

Answer (score 0):

To grab the last element in the array `urlParts`, just use:

```
var last = urlParts[urlParts.length-1];
```

As an alternate way to do this, you could do:

```
var last = currentUrl.substr( currentUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1 );
```